# Server sent events, nullpointer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jersey

```
@Singleton @Path("broadcast") public class UserCreatedEventsResource {
private Sse sse;
private SseBroadcaster broadcaster;

@Inject
public UserCreatedEventsResource(@Context final Sse sse) {
    this.sse = sse;
    this.broadcaster = sse.newBroadcaster();
}

@POST
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String broadcastMessage(String message) {
    final OutboundSseEvent event = sse.newEventBuilder()
            .name("message")
            .mediaType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
            .data(String.class, message)
            .build();

    broadcaster.broadcast(event);

    return "Message '" + message + "' has been broadcast.";
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
public void listenToBroadcast(@Context SseEventSink eventSink) {
    this.broadcaster.register(eventSink);
} }
```

I had a nullpointer exception, but after reimporting the projekt with maven it dissappeared.

I think I did the rebuild once before but it did not work, and now I did it again and its working fine.

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace?

Comment: 1. java.lang.NullPointerException
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on se.group.projektarbete.web.UserCreatedEventsResource
] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at se.group.projektarbete.web.UserCreatedEventsResource.<init>(UserCreatedEventsResource.java:24) ~[classes/:na]

Comment: My problem is the subscribe method, i cant use it , do I need some special dependecy for it? I think I am getting the error because I am using a .register(eventSink) on the broadcaster instead.

Comment: Do you have "jersey-media-sse" in your dependencies? And could you post ResourceConfig or configuration here.

Comment: Yes I do have that dependency.

Comment: "AT"Configuration
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        packages("se.group.projektarbete.web");
    }

    "AT"Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule());
    }
}

Comment: When I reimported the project with maven, the nullpointer disapeared. I had to add "AT"Inject on the constructor for the code to run. But I got a different error now 2018-05-29 13:13:15.273 ERROR 5380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[.g.p.c.JerseyConfig]    : Allocate exception for servlet [se.group.projektarbete.config.JerseyConfig]

javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath, or use ParameterMessageInterpolator instead